# Extract dictionaries from JSON where a field value starts with a certain string

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to parse this json so that I can extract all dictionaries from the input where the "uri" field does not start with the string "/themes"

```
  {
    "version": 0,
    "permissionMask": 2,
    "creationDate": "2022-06-09T14:42:41",
    "updateDate": "2021-11-17T06:48:52",
    "label": "webPageView.css",
    "uri": "/themes/default/webPageView.css",
    "resourceType": "file"
  },
  {
    "version": 0,
    "permissionMask": 2,
    "creationDate": "2022-06-09T14:42:43",
    "updateDate": "2021-11-17T06:48:48",
    "label": "workflow_icons_sprite@05x.png",
    "uri": "/internal/default/images/workflow_icons_sprite@05x.png",
    "resourceType": "file"
  }
```

so the output would only contain

```
  {
    "version": 0,
    "permissionMask": 2,
    "creationDate": "2022-06-09T14:42:43",
    "updateDate": "2021-11-17T06:48:48",
    "label": "workflow_icons_sprite@05x.png",
    "uri": "/internal/default/images/workflow_icons_sprite@05x.png",
    "resourceType": "file"
  }
```

I've tried

```
jq -r '.[] | select( .[].uri | ( startswith( "/themes" ) | not ) )'
```

but that doesn't seem to work. It simply dumps all the output without filtering out the dictionaries where the uri field starts with "/themes"

Comment: What do you want to produce? an array of of objects or a stream or the URI values alone? Update your question to reflect the exact output desired

Comment: I want the array of dict objects only if the dict key of "uri" contains "/themes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the objects are in an array

```
.[] | select(.uri | startswith( "/themes" ) | not)
```

Gives

```json
{
  "version": 0,
  "permissionMask": 2,
  "creationDate": "2022-06-09T14:42:43",
  "updateDate": "2021-11-17T06:48:48",
  "label": "workflow_icons_sprite@05x.png",
  "uri": "/internal/default/images/workflow_icons_sprite@05x.png",
  "resourceType": "file"
}
```

###### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/rZhiGXsDBYB)

---

Regarding your filter, there's no need for the `.[].uri` inside `select()` since the first `.[]` already loops over the array, so `.` inside the `select()` refers to the object itself.